# Can't Access Variable Because It Is Owned By Another Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I've got everything working except for this call which throws an error no matter how I change things.

This is a WPF Application written in C#.

Things I've Tried:

- Accessing it from a Static Context
- Accessing it from the UI Thread
  (mainWindow.img)

Here is my current code where I access it in a static context:

```
        var worker = new Thread(() => RenderBarcodeImage(imageBytes));
        worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        worker.Name = "RenderBarcodeImage";
        worker.IsBackground = true;
        worker.Start();
        worker.Join();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
            if (mainWindow == null) return;
            mainWindow.PairingBarcodeImage.Stretch = mainWindow.PairingBarcodeImage.Width < MainWindow.img.Width ? Stretch.Uniform : Stretch.None;

            mainWindow.PairingBarcodeImage.Source = MainWindow.img.Source;
            if (mainWindow.PairingBarcodeImage.Source != null)
                mainWindow.SaveBarcodeButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }));
```

No matter what every time I try to access `img` it throws

> InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

How would I access the `img` object from another thread?

Comment: What's the point of spawning an expensive thread if you are going to just sit there and wait for it to complete?  Throw that code away and use **async/await**

Comment: Also, not sure why your UI thread code is bothering with **Dispatcher.Invoke** - the current tread **is** the UI thread

Comment: See marked duplicate for detailed advice on dealing with cross-thread issues in WPF. If you believe that you have done adequate research (something your question shows no evidence of) and are still unable to solve the problem, post a new question that includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a detailed explanation of what you've done to try to solve the problem and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.